# jQuery : Chrome textareas and resize event

Tags: jquery, events, textarea, google-chrome

Chrome makes textareas resizable by default. How can I attach events to the resizing events for the textareas ? Doing the naive `$('textarea').resize(function(){...})` does nothing.

Comment: You could check the width before and after a click.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't look like you can specifically attach events to resizing a textarea. The resize event fires when the window is resized.

Answer (score 7):

I can't test this right now, but according to [**this forum entry**](http://www.wohill.com/design/396/Google-Chrome%27s-resizable-textarea.html) it can be disabled using:

```
style="resize: none;"
```

unlike stated in that entry, `max-width` and `max-height` won't cut it - thanks to @Jonathan Sampson for the info.

Comment: +1 `resize:none` disables it. `max-width` and `max-height` didn't: http://jsbin.com/inane

Answer (score 5):

Here's a jQuery plugin written using CoffeeScript. Idea from Jonathan Sampson.

```
$.fn.sizeId = ->                                                         
    return this.height() + "" + this.width()                             

$.fn.textAreaResized = (callback) ->                                     
    this.each ->                                                         
        that = $ this                                                    
        last = that.sizeId() 
        that.mousedown ->                                                
            last = that.sizeId()                                         
        that.mousemove ->                                                  
            callback(that.get(0)) if last isnt that.sizeId()
```

You can build it to Javascript on the CoffeeScript's homepage

http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/

Use the "Try CoffeeScript" button.

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question, but someone else had the same one in IRC, so I decided to solve it here: http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/Z7HDn/

Everyone's right that Chrome doesn't capture the resize event and that Chrome doesn't capture the mousedown, so you need to set the init state and then handle changes through mouseup:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   // set init (default) state   
   var $test = jQuery('#test');

   $test.data('w', $test.outerWidth());
   $test.data('h', $test.outerHeight()); 

   $test.mouseup(function(){
      var $this = jQuery(this);
      if (  $this.outerWidth()  != $this.data('w') 
         || $this.outerHeight() != $this.data('h')
         )
         alert( $this.outerWidth()  + ' - ' + $this.data('w') + '\n' 
              + $this.outerHeight() + ' - ' + $this.data('h'));

      // set new height/width
      $this.data('w', $this.outerWidth());
      $this.data('h', $this.outerHeight()); 
   });

});
```

HTML

```
<textarea id="test"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is jquery-resize which once included just makes your given line work:
http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Epeli's answer I've tried to start on a clean solution to trigger a resize() event on mousedown: http://jsfiddle.net/cburgmer/jv5Yj/3/
However it only works with Firefox as Chrome doesn't seem to trigger mousedown on the resize handler. However it does trigger mouseup.