# Is there a JavaScript event to detect when the size changes for a div using the CSS3 resize property?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using the CSS3 resize property to create a vertically scrollable div:

```
.mydiv {
  resize: vertical
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Chrome puts a little set of diagonal hatches in the bottom right corner of the div which I can now use to resize it.

Is there any way to detect the resize in JavaScript?  I've tried using a DOM4 [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) on the div's attributes but it doesn't fire anything.  I can use mouse events on the div but it's hacky (mousedown doesn't fire so I have to listen to all mousemove's and detect if it's near that corner.)

Comment: I added another update.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear possible to attach an event to the resize using the Chrome textarea handles.  Read this: **[jQuery : Chrome textareas and resize event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096271/jquery-chrome-textareas-and-resize-event)**

I tried using the DOMSubtreeModified but it doesn't modify the DOM so that doesn't work.

**--UPDATE--** If you want to use jQuery UI then it is possible.  See this: **http://jsfiddle.net/kJNsB/1/**

```
$("textarea").resizable({
    resize: function() {
        $("body").append("<pre>resized! Height:"+$(this).height()+" /// Width:"+$(this).width()+"</pre>");
    }
});
```

**--UPDATE--** This guy has it figured out! **http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-resize/examples/resize/**

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm looking for a plain vanilla JavaScript solution.  Also, looks like jQuery implements it with polling which seems undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

HTML:

```
<textarea onresize="Resizing()"></textarea>
```

Javascript:

```
function Resizing(){
   console.log("Resizing..");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now only window object can have a resize event handler. But you can use getBoundingClientRect() on an element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize

> In some earlier browsers it was possible to register resize event handlers on any HTML element. It is still possible to set onresize attributes or use addEventListener() to set a handler on any element. However, **resize events are only fired on the window object** (i.e. returned by document.defaultView). Only handlers registered on the window object will receive resize events.
>
> There is a proposal to allow all elements to be notified of resize changes.